# Image overlay in android native camera

Tags: android, image, camera, overlay

I am new into the android development environment. I want to know if there is a way to overlay an image into the android native camera, so I do not have to program an custom camera, just call the native camera, but into preview an image will be showed. I have tried many ways, but none of them seems to work.

Here is the code I use to shoot the picture and save the image:

```
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    File pictureDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myPics");

    String pictureName = getPictureName();
    File imageFile = new File(pictureDirectory, pictureName);
    Uri pictureUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, pictureUri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

Something like this face grid, but on top of the native camera:

!https://lh6.ggpht.com/8_x6orazogmW3sU9pnev2EzOalJkKi8ext1qzNTbbHdFCP5W0eKdVJk3KnMijf0nQw=h900

Thank You!

Comment: Do you realize that `native camera` could have different preview sizes, various buttons at different places and lots of overlays also?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if there is a way to overlay an image into the android native camera, so I do not have to program an custom camera, just call the native camera, but into preview an image will be showed. Something like this face grid, but on top of the native camera

No.

First, there are thousands of Android device models. These devices will have dozens, if not hundreds, of "android native camera" apps, as many device manufacturers frequently ship a customized camera app.

Second, your code is not invoking an "android native camera" app. Your code is invoking the user's choice of what camera app to use, among the camera apps that the user has installed that support `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. The user can easily choose to use some other camera app, if they prefer that camera app to the one that shipped with their device. So now you have hundreds, if not thousands, of additional camera apps to consider. Any of those could be what a given user is using.

Third, there is no requirement that all camera apps have an identical user interface. The size and position of the camera preview can vary. Not only will they vary between apps, but even the same app might vary the size and position of the camera preview between versions of that app, as apps can and do get updated.

Fourth, you have no good way of determining when any of these camera apps happens to be in the foreground.